# Weird problems while getting ID just after saving data

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have different models which are an extension of another one.

```
classes (SubModel1, SubModel2, ..,6) extends -> HighModel extends -> Appmodel
```

Everytime I save data in each submodel I call a function in my HighModel to save the id of the just saved SubModel. 
It works perfectly with five SubModels, but in one the id is always:
 `($shouldBeThisId - 1)`in both add and edit functions.... o_O

Here's my add function:

```
    public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->M18Tab->create();
        if ($this->M18Tab->save($this->request->data)) {
            $data = $this->M18Tab->findById($this->M18Tab->id); //<---problem's here
            if($this->M18Tab->M18Model->saveVersion($data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The m18 tab has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $this->M18Tab->id));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error with versioning system'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The m18 tab could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    //view variables
}
```

ok. so after saving I recall the "just saved data" and pass it to `$this->SubModel->HighModel->saveVersion($data)`. and the weird thing is that if I try to force the id to find:

```
$data = $this->M18Tab->findById(33);
```

it'll still find the id preceding the just inserted one :0.

what could this be caused by? the code is the same for all 6 models and in only one I have this issue..

Comment: "it still find the id before the just inserted one ", I don't understand what you mean by this. You don't get the 33 record when trying to force that find?

Comment: I don't know cake at all but most model systems do not immediately flush so that could be the source of your troubles

Comment: yep.. the last one i got was 37 =S

Comment: I also tried $data = $this->M18Tab->read(null,$this->M18Tab->id); and still get the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment/suggestion than an answer, but anyway...

If you're adding a new record, after calling save, you can get it's ID via:

```
$this->MyModel->getInsertId();
```

See that method in [the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html#model-getinsertid). I know the id should also be available at $this->MyModel->id, but since it's not working in this case, you might want to try:

```
$data = $this->M18Tab->findById($this->M18Tab->getInsertId());
```

Comment: already did it... :( unfortunately even if i delete all the records and create a new one it still do this absurd thing.

Comment: Have you tried fetching the ID via a raw query? Like $this->M18Tab->query('SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 1 ORDER BY id DESC'); or something like that?